# In visualforce page onclicking 1st button activate 2nd button

Tags: javascript, visualforce

In my visualforce page there is 2 buttons(Insert and Continue). When Continue button is clicked then Insert button should be shown in page otherwise Insert button should be hidden.

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons Id="buttonContainer">
<apex:commandButton value="Insert" rerender="mainForm"rendered= 
{!showInsertButton}" onClick="javascript:fnInsertCompany();return false;" />
<apex:commandButton action="{!continue}" value="Continue" 
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Comment: Unless you post the actual code, the best we can do is empathize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used **rendered** attribute to your Insert button. You can easily render this button in a conditional logic.

In **Continue** button, the action is `continue` i.e. you have a method called `continue()` in your controller.

So, globally make the `showInsertButton = false` AND in `continue()` method, make the

```
showInsertButton = true
```

Thats all.